# Text of xml element not reassigned to new value

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I have an xml defined as string my_xml.
Then I tried to increase amount of strings and change some values.

```
my_xml = """<root><foo><bar>spamm.xml</bar></foo></root>"""
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
tree = et.fromstring(my_xml )
el = list(tree)[0].copy()
tree.insert(0, el)
tree.insert(0, el)
cnt = 0 
elements = [elem for elem in tree.iter() if elem.text is not None]
for elem in elements:
    if cnt !=0:
        print elem.text[:4]+str(cnt)+elem.text[5:]
        elem.text= elem.text[:4]+str(cnt)+elem.text[5:] # strange behavour
    cnt +=1

print et.tostring(tree)
```

Why `elem.text= elem.text[:4]+str(cnt)+elem.text[5:]` string does not reassigned `elem.text` to new value?

Expected output

```
<root>
<foo><bar>spamm.xml</bar></foo>
<foo><bar>spamm1.xml</bar></foo>
<foo><bar>spamm2.xml</bar></foo>
</root>
```

Actual output

```
<root>
<foo><bar>spam2.xml</bar></foo>
<foo><bar>spam2.xml</bar></foo>
<foo><bar>spam2.xml</bar></foo>
</root>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your `copy` phase:

- you should do it for each `el` or both `el` share the same ref
- you should use `copy.deepcopy()` because shallow copy doesn't cut it here

I use python 3, so the `copy()` method doesn't exist. I had to use the `copy` module, using `deepcopy` and on *both* items (or you're copying only once) to make sure all references are duplicated

part of the code I changed (better with a loop):

```
import copy
tree = et.fromstring(my_xml)
for _ in range(2):
    el = copy.deepcopy(list(tree)[0])
    tree.insert(0, el)
```

result:

```
<root><foo><bar>spam1.xml</bar></foo><foo><bar>spam1.xml</bar></foo><foo><bar>spam2.xml</bar></foo></root>
```